# Preserving the order of selected checkboxes during form submission in FLASK

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

suppose i have a simple flask app which provides list of fruits with checkboxes

1. Apple
2. Banana
3. Cherry
4. Date

when user selects checkboxes

1. Dates first
2. Cherry second
3. Banana third
4. Apple fourth

can i populate the same order which i have selected to next page, so that it displays same in next page like below selected order ?

1.Dates
2. Cherry
3. Banana
4. Apple

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

# Sample list of fruits
fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Fig"]

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', fruits=fruits)

@app.route('/select_fruits', methods=['POST'])
def select_fruits():
    selected_order = request.form.get('selected_order')
    if selected_order:
        selected_fruit_values = selected_order.split(',')
    else:
        selected_fruit_values = []

    selected_fruits = [fruit for fruit in fruits if fruit in selected_fruit_values]
    return render_template('selected_fruits.html', selected_fruits=selected_fruits)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fruit Selection</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Select Your Favorite Fruits:</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="/select_fruits">
        <ul id="fruit-list">
            {% for fruit in fruits %}
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="fruit-checkbox" name="fruit" value="{{ fruit }}"> {{ fruit }}<br>
                </label>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="selected_order" id="selected_order" value="">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <script>
        var fruitList = document.getElementById('fruit-list');
        var selectedOrderInput = document.getElementById('selected_order');
        var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.fruit-checkbox');

        checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
            checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
                updateSelectedOrder();
            });
        });

        function updateSelectedOrder() {
            var selectedFruits = Array.from(checkboxes)
                .filter(function (checkbox) {
                    return checkbox.checked;
                })
                .map(function (checkbox) {
                    return checkbox.value;
                });

            selectedOrderInput.value = selectedFruits.join(',');
        }

        updateSelectedOrder(); // Initial update of selected order
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

selected_fruits.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Selected Fruits</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>You have selected the following fruits:</h1>
    <ol>
        {% for selected_fruit in selected_fruits %}
        <li>{{ selected_fruit }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>
    <a href="/">Go back to select more fruits</a>
</body>
</html>
```